# What is a word for whether a value is gross or net?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an API description and have to include the information about whether a numeric value is a gross or net value in the context of it being a price. I could make it a Boolean flag named "gross" and then have it be false for net, but then the name of the flag doesn't actually describe the possible states. Is there a neat word I can use that specifically describes the set of words "gross" and "net" in the context of pricing?

TL;DR: I am looking for a word that describes the state of "grossness" of a price, whether it includes or excludes VAT or sales tax.

Comment: Earnings, Profit, Taxes

Comment: From a programming perspective, I?'m finding it difficult to see where you'd pass _one or the other_ in to the same parameter of the same call...you might have calls that expect net, others that expect gross (or calls that have a full breakdown or net, VAT (at several rates) carriage, discount, etc. and finally gross). If you really want to pass both into one call, an `enum` or similar might be better (`ValueType.Net` vs `ValueType.Gross` etc.). Either way, it's not really EL&U.

Comment: @TripeHound OP is asking for a semanticly meaningful name for the variable or argument you are passing your `ValueType.Net` or `ValueType.Gross` enum to

Comment: @Dan I am looking for a name for the variable that might contain "net" or "gross", ideally.

Comment: AmountType might work, but it's not very specific, as in it doesn't specifically describe a type of amount of a price.

Comment: @TripeHound an enum would be great, but how do I name it? ValueType would work, but is there a better expression that is more specific to currency?

Comment: Following on the suggestions how about *PriceType*?

Comment: Seems inappropriate for this site. You should call it is_gross or IsGross. The end.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest something different: `ProfitType`.

It seems to me that when you talk about gross or net, you're talking about how much you get to pocket.

In fact, there are actually three types of profit: gross, operating, and net. (From [Understanding Profit Metrics: Gross, Operating and Net Profits](http://Understanding%20Profit%20Metrics:%20Gross,%20Operating%20and%20Net%20Profits).)

---

I was confused by this concept at first, until I realized that the value given here is not necessarily the sticker price of an item. It's an internal-only bookkeeping value. So, while (for instance) `StickerPrice` is 10, if `TotalTaxes` is 2, then `ProfitValue` would be 8 if `ProfitType` is 'Net'. (Without taking other expenses into account.)